# What Browser-Based Tools can I use to Check the Efficiency and Memory Usage Of My JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am currently reading *High Performance JavaScript* by Nicholas C. Zakas and in the book he says things like:

> Comparing the two pieces of code shows that using the Selectors API is
>   2 to 6 times faster across browsers (Figure 3-6).

[image: Figure 3-6. The benefit of using the Selectors API instead of iterating over the results of getElementsbyTagName()]

**What I'm looking for is a browser based tool that lets me capture and measure the performance of a given piece of JavaScript and compare it against another script that uses a different approach (e.g., using the Selector API vs `getElementsByTagName`).**

I've used Chrome and Firebug, but neither of them really seem to give me the kind of comparisons he's doing here. Am I using these tools incorrectly or is there a new tool I'm not familiar with that I should be using?

Comment: chrome has the `Timeline`. click on `Memory` or `Timelines (Events)`, hit the record button below (circle), and let your JS run. You can see the timings, as well as memory use.

Comment: What *exactly* is the question? What do the charts have to do with memory usage and stress testing?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 The question is: What browser-based tools can I use to track the performance of my JavaScript code in order to make performance enhancements? I haven't found a tool that easily allows me to compare the performance of two approaches to the same problem (e.g., using the selector api vs `getElementsByTagName`). I've gone ahead and edited the question to clarify exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular approach is just use the free online services of http://jsperf.com/.

Or [clone it](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com) from github.

It has one big advantage over manual testing: It uses a Java Applet which gives access to a nanosecond timer, while JS timers (Date objects) can only resolve to milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome developers tools are the way to go. There are three awesome features.

1. Timeline. This will show you the rendering time of any executing javascript on a timeline graph.
2. Heap snapshot. This guy will take a snapshot of your current JS, including all of your chain. It also shows you how much memory each element is taking - provides a good way to find places your code is chewing.
3. CPU Profile. Shows how much CPU usage a function is eating up, also useful for finding places to optimize and perhaps introduce web workers.

If you use the Chrome beta channel check out the Speed Tracer extension (by Google). It's basically an enhanced timeline. If you're a jQuery guy the beta also has CSS Selector Profiling. I have yet to use so I can't speak to its uses.